# WordPress book for graphic designers?

Tags: design, books

Is there a good WordPress book intended for graphic designers? I've started working with a friend in an arrangement where he designs a site and I build it in WordPress. This works great since I have the design sense of a blind monkey. He would like to learn more about WordPress and how best to design for it. I'm familiar with several good WordPress books, but most of them are intended for designer/developers. I'm looking for something that will serve as a guideline, offering suggestions for design conventions that are well suited to WordPress. Are there any such books? If there's not a book specifically aimed at designers, which other book would you suggest?

Comment: Are you more precisely asking about creating WordPress Themes? Is the Graphic Designer more a Web Designer or more a Graphic Designer? You wrote in another comment a solid grasp on webdesign, are you aware of the Theme Development Checklist? http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development_Checklist - it must not be helpful for designer but probably it helps to better scope what is interesting for the designer part. Good question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some said this [rockable book](http://rockablepress.com/books/rockstar-wordpress-designer/) is awesome, though I don't buy it myself. I'm backend wordpress developer not front end, so I guess this book is not for me.

Answer (score 1):

What about just taking a look at different themes that are available. I'm not sure what kind of guidelines you're looking for exactly, but you may be able to get a general idea from observing what's already out there. Some good sites for this are:

- http://wordpress.org/extend/themes/
- http://www.wpthemesfree.com/

Answer (score 0):

This post was just made on reddit the other day, some solid books based on 2 important design factors, layouts and typography. They are not wordpress specific but the ideas still apply.
http://www.reddit.com/r/web_design/comments/e2uo2/webbit_where_can_i_learn_web_design_not_just_the/

Comment: The person I'm looking for a book for already has a solid grasp on webdesign. I'm just looking for something to help them learn WordPress from a designer's perspective.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend "Build Your Own Wicked WordPress Themes" by SitePoint:
http://www.sitepoint.com/books/wordpress1/